# Count how many times same word appear in a binary tree

Tags: c++

I do a binary tree with string and I compare the string with the function compare, in order to put them in the binray tree. I do this successfully, but my problem is that I have to count how many times a word appear in the binary tree, but I have no idea how to do this.
Thank you for your help !

This is my code to search a value :

```
void Node::sameNode(string value)
{
if (value == this->data)
{
    count++;
}
else
{
    if (left && value < this->data)
    {
        left->sameNode(value);
    }
    if (right && value > this->data)
    {
        right->sameNode(value);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the right place for assignment work

Comment: Do you know how to find a value in a BST?

Comment: I put my code to find if the value that I want to put is the same as the current value, but from this point how to count how many times appears a word form the root

Comment: I don't understand the `left` and `right` searches. The function never reaches that point because it always returns at the first comparison with `value`. Remove the `else{ return false; }`, then return `true` if either `left->search(value)` or `right->search(value)` return `true`, then at the end return `false` if neither searches return a result.

Comment: OK, you edited the code. Questions: **1)** Where do you keep your `count` variable? Is it global?, **2)** What do you want your method to _do_?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
count = 0
for each value in traverse(tree)
    if value == word
        count++
```

Where `traverse(tree)` returns a generator, or an iterator range, that traverses the tree and `value` is the string stored in the current node.